# compress CSS code but STILL be able to work on it? (in dreamweaver)

Tags: css, dreamweaver, minify

I am trying to compress my CSS code on the server for faster load times, BUT I would still like to be able to USE it locally in Dreamweaver (so dreamweaver can actually DISPLAY my page when I am in split view).

I have tried both MiniFy as well as this method: http://www.ethanandjamie.com/blog/85-php-gzip-css-files and a done loads more research.

The problem is that these scripts do not allow dreamweaver to DISPLAY the CSS file while working in design view.  So everything is not styled.

Anyone have any suggestions or run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would store the file uncompressed and compress the file dynamically upon request. For instance, your "CSS" file could be "myCss.php", which would be a php page that would compress the file (and possibly cache it).

This way, you never need to deal compressing your CSS files, and dreamweaver has no reason to display them oddly.

Comment: That is one of the options I tried.  However, whenever you use this format... <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somename.php"/>  then Dreamweaver does not USE the css inside the .php file.... which is my problem.

Comment: You *could* intercept the request, and compress it... but I'm a .net programer at the moment, so this kind of "http handler" functionality escapes me when dealing with a non IIS server. :/

Comment: The idea would be to catch requests to any ".css" extension and redirect it to a generic "css compressor and cacher" php page. This is advantageous, as you would only ever have to do this once for *any number* of css files on your server. However, it *may* cause decreased response time... but possibly better load times.

Comment: I get what you mean. That seems like a bit of work though. If only dreamweaver wasn't so picky about file name extensions. :)

Comment: That brings up a good point... are those style sheet extensions configurable? I have no idea.